# Ignore the files I'm working on during merge

Tags: git

We've recently switched to Git from a simple-to-use centralized VCS. To ease the transition, we're using SourceTree as a GUI for Git. One of my colleagues asked if there was some way to emulate the workflow he had grown accustomed to:

Let's say he was working on a project with three files: A, B, and C. He might checkout A and make changes to it. While he made changes to A, others were making changes to A, B and C, and committing their changes to the VCS repo. Using the VCS client or Visual Studio, he would periodically pull the latest B and C to his working dir, but never A, i.e., if others made changes to A, he ignored them until he was done working on A. At that point I guess he merged the changes.

I told him that Git isn't going to work that way, i.e., on a file-by-file basis. I suggested that if he's working on A he can periodically merge remote changes to A, B and C. If there are conflicts in A, he can resolve them then. (He'll have to eventually anyway.) I considered adding A to .gitignore and removing it from the repo (not at all correct), adding a merge=ours gitattribute for A (seems more appropriate for a config file, not the set of source files he happens to be working on this week), or using assume-unchanged or skip-worktree (again, doesn't seem appropriate for ever-changing sets of source files he happens to be working on now).

Does he just need to get used to the new workflow, or is there something I've missed in Git that will emulate the old centralized VCS workflow he's used to?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, in this case, If everyone is working on this code in such a shared-code manner, the best way I would see to go about it would just be to have him pull in the branch with the updates to B and C periodically and deal with any merge conflicts in A as they appear. With any luck, and an appropriate branching-system where features are separated out in a reasonable manner, he would be the only working on the portion of the feature in A that affects itself, and if other people are doing things that directly conflict with how his particular piece (or entire) of the feature is working, then perhaps the work isn't being separated out in an optimal manner.

That being said, if someone DOES make a change in A that affects him, it's probably well for him to know about it as soon as possible, since as soon as he merges his feature back into the main trunk of the operation, the longer he waited to deal with those merges, the greater the divergence, and the greater the chance that a merge could become borderline unmanageable.

One of the beauties of things like Git are that you can take a situation like this, and build a pattern of software development around avoiding exactly these type of problems, where a good SoC (Separation of Concerns) leads to a beautiful software process that will weed out these types of conflicts in their majority.

hope that helps a little bit!

Comment: Thanks Will. That's pretty much what I told him, but it's good to have a second opinion.